# Escaping square brackets when using LIKE operator in sql

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I am trying to search for this string `[Name].[Names - Software].[Names Delivery]`

II have the following but its not finding anything:

```
DECLARE @string AS VARCHAR(50) = '%\[Name].[Names - Software].[Names Delivery]%'

SELECT  Name
FROM    sys.procedures
WHERE   OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE @string ESCAPE '\'
```

How do I change `@string` so it will find all instances of the string?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Also, sample data as DDL+DML and desired results would help.

Comment: @jarlh good point - added.

Comment: [Read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), especially about *escaping*...

Comment: Btw: It took about three seconds to find the existing question... Please do some research first...